# Python in 2.80: How to get the base color texture from a Material

Tags: python, export

If I have a bpy.types.Material, how do I get the textureslot assigned to the base color if there is one?

Comment: Node trees can be complex, so that 'base texture' has not always a mean. Do you have some additional information about the node tree?

Comment: Its not in cycles mode. For example Principled BSDF is selected.
Texture was just added to base color by clicking the icon next to base color and selecting the texture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple setting, you can use this:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Color


# try/except if the setting is not as expected
try:
    # Get active object
    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    # Get its first material slot
    material = obj.material_slots[0].material
    # Get the nodes in the node tree
    nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
    # Get a principled node
    principled = next(n for n in nodes if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED')
    # Get the slot for 'base color'
    base_color = principled.inputs['Base Color'] #Or principled.inputs[0]
    # Get its default value (not the value from a possible link)
    value = base_color.default_value
    # Translate as color
    color = Color( (value[0], value[1], value[2]) )
    print( color )

    # Get the link
    link = base_color.links[0]
    link_node = link.from_node
    print( link_node.image.name )
except:
    print( 'not found' )
```

Comment: That is useful, but I was looking for the texture that has been assigned to this color.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Don't know why you've been downvoted... sometimes strange things here...

Comment: If you feel there is a lot of research effort put into this python question, you can always upvote it @lemon Upvoted your answer because of being nice and trying to help.

Comment: @brockmann, I understand but considering that we should dv nearly 80% of the questions

Comment: @brockmann for instance the last bounty about gizmos was in fact "I should find myself but if someone knows and do it for me" but has been uv. Globally this may be a subject for the meta (probably has been asked before).

Comment: Agree @lemon However, I don't think there is something strange going on in case the question is just an one-liner.

Comment: @brockmann ok, could remove this word np. Was strange because why this one and not another one. But if dv, should comment a bit (I rarely dv but always comment to explain if i do).

Comment: Yeah, agree. Although I'm not the downvoter, I understand the reason @lemon